# Chanukah candles lit by a non-Jew

Tags: chanuka

Is a Jew allowed to recite the Chanukah blessings if the candle in the menorah was lit by a non-Jew? (Specifically, the shamash was lit by a non-Jew, and then from that shamash, a Jew lit the Chanukah candle.)

Comment: Hi Chana, welcome to Mi Yodeya, hope you've had a chance to click the ? at the top and go through the Tour and Help Center.